# How to get Socket server address and port of an instant messenger?

Tags: python, sockets, server, serversocket, python-sockets

I am using an instant messenger bot. Recently Instant messenger(palringo) has changed the connection setting, and I have no idea how to get new socket server address and port that can connect bot to the Instant Messenger.

Code:

```
 sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        server_address = ('80.69.129.4',12345);
        print('Attempting to connect to the server')
        try:
            sock.connect(server_address)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the Host or Addr
maybe you can use some command to input them

```
#!/usr/bin/python

HOST=raw_input('please input HOST: ')
PORT=raw_input('please input PORT: ')
```

then you change the HOST and PORT

```
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST,PORT))
```

Comment: sorry,I understand the wrong topic.maybe You can consult the official customer service staff